# c# can't access file with relative path

Tags: c#, path, relative-path

I have a text file where I write some errors. If the string file path is written in absolute method, `string filePath = @"E:\server\publish\Exceptions.txt";` it works as expected. But if I use a relative path, the file isn't written. The way I use relative path: `string filePath = @"../../Exceptions.txt";`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "/" instead of "\" in the relative path?

Comment: The path is relative to the current folder. Are you aware where you currently are (you might take a look at Directory.GetCurrentDirectory for example)?

Comment: Have you tried executing `Path.GetFullPath(filePath);` to see if the System can resolve the location of your file?

Comment: @SvenBardos, not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use GetFullPath as in [similar question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/241652/c-relative-absolute-path.html)

```cs
 string sCurrentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;            
 string sFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sCurrentDirectory, @"../../Exceptions.txt");
 string sFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(sFile);
```

Comment: This worked for me:


            string sCurrentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string sFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sCurrentDirectory, "..\publish\Exceptions.txt");
            string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(sFile);